# openni driver installation

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing openni drivers for kinect and I successfully performed a 'hg clone [https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers'](https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers%27).  However when I cd into drivers and try to perform a 'make' I get a "git: Command not found".  What does this mean and can anyone help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12504/openni-driver-installation/) by [GenePSmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/1562/genepsmith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

git is a version control system. sudo apt-get install git should install it...

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-07-27**:
Please checkmark this, since he answered your question.